# Como puxar arquivos do repositório sem gerar commit de merge?

Tags: git, github

Como posso obter os novos arquivos do repositório sem aplicar o commit `Merge branch 'master' of...`?

Estou utilizando:

```
git pull
```

Ele puxa tudo bacaninha, porém, cria esse commit de merge. Como faço para ter somente os commits do repositório remoto, ignorando esse commit legal de merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o git `rebase`:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Assim, o git colocará todos os **seus** commits no topo dos commits da branch remota, sem fazer o commit de *merge*. Esta é uma reclamação bem comum ao usar o Git, pois sem ter este hábito de utilizar o `rebase` você acaba tendo estes commits de merge "sujando" as branches.

Contudo, quando ocorre algum conflito, o git rebase acaba não sendo a melhor opção.

Comment: Se o seu `HEAD` estiver sujo, pode fazer um `git stash` para esconder essa sujeira. Eu costumo fazer `git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop`, que esconde a sujeira, faz o `rebase` e suja novamente